# What is killing my power adapters?

Tags: power-supply, power

### Hardware

I have two [Acer S230HL](http://a.co/7UdA9N9)'s and an [ASUS PG278Q](http://a.co/19oow46) (hooked up to a custom PC build).

### Background

3 months ago on an exceptionally hot day, the power to the house flickered off and immediately back on, after which one of my 3 PC monitor's was unresponsive.

Thankfully it had not been fried but instead, the power adapter for the Acer monitor took the bullet, which was a little under $30 to replace. I called the power company to ask wtf happened and they claimed they saw no evidence of a power surge or spike on their end at the time frame I gave, but that because of the heat lots of people were using A/C and that may have caused a very small "undetectable" spike. Frankly, it felt like the service rep was trying to give me as little info as possible, perhaps thinking I might take them to small claims court or someshit (which I'd have done if anything actually expensive had been fried).

I had no interest in that and just wanted to find out what happened so I could prevent it from repeating. After no help from the company I spoke to some neighbors and nobody else had experienced a power flicker at the time I did. Finally, I checked over my power strips and found that one was not surge protected at all and another for a laughably small protection. So I upgraded all of my power strips to high Joule surge protectors (specifically [this](http://a.co/gyKYLsJ) rated for 3,940 Joules and [this](http://a.co/fXAAlTP) for 1,240 Joules).

### Seemingly fine...

Throughout the next 3 months I did experience the same power flicker 4-5 times (none due to storms), two of them on the same day, but with no repercussions to my electronics.

### RIP

Then last week it struck again and once more killed the power adapter (to the same monitor as before, ie: it killed the replacement adapter). Before declaring it dead I checked everything over, all the wires and connections were tight and no power was being drawn by the adapter (small green LED on the adapter brick itself is out). I did not bother calling the power company (I should have).

It appears that the same exact issue has occurred only this time with everything on high voltage surge protectors. It's worth noting that the power adapter that died this time was indeed connected to the weaker 1,240 Joule protector.

I rent part of this house so I am unaware of how much amperage the others consume, but I do know this is not a simple tripping of the breakers (since no flip of the breaker switch was required for power to return). The homeowners and 1 other tenant were not even home last week when my adapter died.

### This begs the question

What is killing my power adapters? Is it a power spike or surge? An issue of drawing too much amperage from the circuit breaker? Something else?

**Disclaimer:** *I do not fully understand electrical wiring, how the power grid works, the differences between voltage, amperage, watts, coulombs, and Joules but have a very basic familiarity. I'm more than willing to learn whatever it takes (and competent enough, I'd like to think) so please don't shy away from technical explanations.*

Comment: You'd have to do a post mortem of the adapter to be sure of the exact cause, but getting a power conditioner would not be a terrible start in preventing this from happening again.

Comment: I don't think it's the power company, but an issue of the electrical wiring within the home. I'm not an electrical expert, but it sounds like outlet you're plugged into may have a faulty ground. Or a bad ground somewhere.

Comment: There is more to power then just voltage. I'm not an expert (but know more then the average person) - and I wonder if this is caused by a piece of equipment (possibly outside your property) distorting the AC signal and possibly pushing very short high voltage spikes through the line - such that fuses don't have time to react, but damaging to switched mode power supplies?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams any suggested reading on how to learn to take apart the power adapter and figure out the cause?

Comment: @DrZoo could be, I'll float that by the landlord and ask who did the wiring

Comment: I didn’t know you rented your place. Talk to your landlord about the power flickers. It’s their responsibility legally. They can have an electrician and/or the power company check things out. If you’re having that many flickers something is definitely wrong.

Comment: Ty @sawdust, was gunna point out the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting a UPS, 500-800va should be more than enough for 3 monitors.  It seems like poor quality power adapters, maybe you got generic version or a counterfit or they have some other defect.

The interesting thing here is it isn't cause problems with any of your other devices.  If it was extreme line conditions it would effect more than just your monitors.

A UPS would probably solve the problem as it has a built-in battery which would power the devices for the brief seconds the power goes out.

Now, if you want to actually know what the problem is your going to need a data recorder to record data per second then after the next outage you can review the logs.

Look at the voltages, if the voltage dips significantly then you might be over drawing the line.  However, you will need to, potential, review weeks of data to determine the normal voltage and how much it varies, if any, during each hour of the day.

Comment: I agree w/downvote.  A UPS is not the solution, unless it's an online type that truly isolates the equipment from the power mains.

Comment: @sawdust  Then get an "online" kind and be done with it.

Comment: The 2nd adapter was for sure a generic, the first the original adapter directly from Acer.

Agreed the fact that no other devices have been affected during any of these flickers is what's been puzzling for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

> What is killing my power adapters? Is it a power spike or surge?

Yes, most likely power surges/spikes are occurring when you notice the power incidents.

When you had the first failure of a power adapter, your equipment did not have any surge protection.  So in hindsight, obviously your equipment was vulnerable to a power surge/spike.

Then you installed two *"high Joule surge protectors"*.
This was adequate to protect your equipment through the next 3 months during which you did experience similar power incidents 4-5 times.

However your assumption that these *"high Joule surge protectors"* would continue to provide full protection is fallacious.
**Surge protectors do not last forever**.

The typical component used to absorb an electrical surge/spike is a MOV, which will *degrade* as it is exposed to excessive electrical energy.
The MOV will eventually fail, and can act as a short and pass the surge/spike to the equipment that it is supposed to protect.

So after 4 or 5 power incidents, **your equipment may have no or minimal surge protection**.
When the most recent power incident occurred, the lowest-rated surge protector allowed another power adapter to fail.
So in hindsight, your equipment was probably again vulnerable to a power surge/spike.

Your description is completely consistent with the known fact that MOVs and surge protectors will and do degrade with exposure to power incidents.

References:
[Why (and When) You Need to Replace Your Surge Protector](https://www.howtogeek.com/212375/why-and-when-you-need-to-replace-your-surge-protector/)
[Why You Should Periodically Replace Your Surge Protectors](https://lifehacker.com/why-you-should-periodically-replace-your-surge-protecto-1693447062)

Comment: >Surge protectors do not last forever.

I know, both of the ones I bought have indicator LED's for when they require replacement. All of them are green still. 

One of the links you provided said I cannot rely on these LED's but doesn't explain why. To me seems like it's in the manufacturer's best interests to have these indicators switch off sooner rather than later so I buy more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

1. A *higher* voltage rating is a *disadvantage*. The voltage should be clipped as close to mains voltage ([120 VAC in NA, 240 VAC many other places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity)) as feasible to protect equipment.
2. The more *Joules*, the better. This is the amount of *energy* the surge protector can absorb before it is fried. Get a protector with a *fuse*, so that should the surge protector be damaged, the device being protected is disconnected.
3. Have the landlord install a [service entrance surge protector](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-120-Volt-240-Volt-Residential-Whole-House-Surge-Protector-R02-51110-SRG/202993881) if one is not present.
4. Check the power entrance cable, or the voltage on different circuits. A damaged neutral connection can cause an imbalance across a two phase line. That means that one set of  circuits in the house might have perhaps 40 or 60 V, while the other set would have 180 or 200 V (assuming 240 VAC split phase house wiring).

[image: Service drop and neutral]

From the ground, if the cables are visible, check for any obvious break in the neutral line. Do not climb or get close to look!

If you know how to use a multimeter *safely*, check the voltage at various outlets in different rooms. Try this both with and without a large load on one side, e.g. vacuum cleaner or small space heater. There is no reason for concern if it's within [5% of nominal](https://www.quick220.com/blog/the-voltage-range-in-your-home/).

5. For greater safety, an uninterruptible power supply helps prevent surges, too.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and terminology correction. How would I go about checking the power entrance cable/multiple circuits? A [multimeter](http://a.co/9pPBfD2)?

Comment: @Murkantilism, that info has been added.

Comment: I've rented a duplex and have no qualms about looking outside to see if the neutral is OK. Also note the comment about using a multimeter *safely*.